# Laravel clear all SQS queues using localstack

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-sqs, localstack

When I start a new day at work, I open all the containers again, and when I run `php artisan queue:work` or listen I expect nothing to run, since everything is fresh and I haven't done anything yet .. but for some reason it's trying to execute old queues.
I am using SQS queues on localstack

I tried clearing everything, using:
`php artisan queue:flush`

Also I used `php artisan queue:restart`

I checked `php artisan queue:failed` to make sure that nothing is in any file

I also deleted `recorded_api_calls.json` just to make ure its not from there .. and its not

Does anybody have any idea where all the random queue calls may come from ?

Comment: stil having this issue, even after 6 months ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is useful to someone. This command should list the queues on localstack sqs

```
docker exec -it localstack_container_name aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --no-sign-request sqs list-queues
```

You need to replace `localstack_container_name` with container name from you local `docker ps` output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do this via Laravel, but I login to the AWS Console and purge the queue from there.